# How to Format Number field in Crystals Reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have created a DataSet, in my projet, that is linked to my Crystal report. Howhever, when I run the application there is decimal with numeric fields. How can I remove them?
In DataSet  I  have changed the datatype to Int32.And when I take mouse over the field in crystal Report it show (string). How can I fix it.
Thanks....

Comment: Convert the field into number using the formula and then specify the format of the formula field. This will work, I have been using the same way.

Comment: I fix it by deleting the field that I dragged  from DataSet. And then change the type to Int32 in Dataset and again drag the field to report. Than it show the expected result.Thanks for replay.